# Text Alignment Issue in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a input field and it has some text in it. On click of a button I want to change the text-align to center, left and right.

It works in every browser but not in IE9.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test for Text Align</title>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
        #testBox{
            text-align: left;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id ="testBox" name="testBox" value="testBox" maxlength="32" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" onClick="testFunction('centeralign')" name="centeralign" id="centeralign" value="centeralign"/>
        <input type="button" onClick="testFunction('leftalign')" name="leftalign" id="leftalign" value="leftalign"/>
        <input type="button" onClick="testFunction('rightalign')" name="rightalign" id="rightalign" value="rightalign"/>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function testFunction(el){
        var testTextBox  =  document.getElementById("testBox");
        if(el == "centeralign"){
            testTextBox.style.textAlign = "center";
        }else if (el == "leftalign") {
            testTextBox.style.textAlign = "left";
        }else if (el == "rightalign") {
            testTextBox.style.textAlign = "right";
        }
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Does not work on any browser . http://jsfiddle.net/RQXFB/

Comment: when you open the above as a html file it works in every browser except IE9 as per my observation and hence wanted help in portal

Comment: Works when you wrap the script in <body> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RQXFB/4/).

Comment: Does not work on IE 10 either. Please be careful with expressions like “every browser”. Instead, list the browsers you have actually tested.

Comment: use css + jquery or css + javascipt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an odd bug in IE (at least some versions of it). It seems that the input box rendering is not updated when its style is changed via an event handler attribute. It seems to help to add the following after the definition of `testTextBox`:

```
testTextBox.value += '';
```

This does not modify the value, since it appends an empty string, but it seems to be sufficient for waking up IE so that it renders the input box with the changed style.

Answer (score 0):

If u have still not got it solved u can get the below code works in ie9 tested js code as ur wish ..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test for Text Align</title>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
        #testBox{
            text-align: left;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id ="testBox" name="testBox" value="testBox" maxlength="32" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" onClick="testFunction('centeralign')" name="centeralign" id="centeralign" value="centeralign"/>
        <input type="button" onClick="testFunction('leftalign')" name="leftalign" id="leftalign" value="leftalign"/>
        <input type="button" onClick="testFunction('rightalign')" name="rightalign" id="rightalign" value="rightalign"/>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function testFunction(el){
        var testTextBox  =  document.getElementById("testBox");
        if(el == "centeralign"){
            testTextBox.style.textAlign = "center";
        }else if (el == "leftalign") {
            testTextBox.style.textAlign = "left";
        }else if (el == "rightalign") {
            testTextBox.style.textAlign = "right";
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Though it would be a good solution, I want to use only Javascript and no Jquery. Could you please help me this way?